# Permanently deleting Email from Default Email app

Tags: stock-email-app

I have a Nexus 4 running Android 4.3 [OTA came on July 29 \m/] and I use the stock e-mail app called "EMail" (I don't like Gmail app). Whenever I delete an app, a folder called Imap/Trash gets created and the mails I delete goes inside this folder. I can see this in the browser. Since I have OCD, I open the browser, delete the mails and remove the label. This is a bit irritating as I have to do this every day. Is there a setting or a tweak or something which lets me delete the mails from my Nexus and move the deleted directly inside Trash (like how it happens in the browser)?

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers :-)

Comment: Thandasoru, (feels difficult to type this if you know what it means ;-)) I am not clear whether you succeeded in removing the email account under scrutiny?

Comment: I am able to delete the email from my phone, but it does not go inside the Trash. It goes inside a folder called Imap/Trash, which is not the expected behavior. In iOS, the default Mail client deletes the mail and sends it to Trash. (Reg. Username: Created it just for fun :-D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android stock email app, you can permanently delete emails if you access the trash folder and delete them from there:

1. Select and email to delete and touch the delete icon;
2. Access the `Trash` folder;
3. Repeat step 1 inside the trash folder for the same email.

With this steps, the email gets permanently deleted from your account.

<sup>I've tested this steps just now to be sure. Anyways, I did not find any setting within the APP or account preferences, in order to do this more seamless!</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but I hope they update the Mail client in such a way that we can delete it directly. I'm sure there will be people like me who don't like the Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen this always happens when you use IMAP to access a GMail account, it used to happen to me years ago when I used Thunderbird mail to connect to GMail over IMAP.

The easiest thing to do is just to hide the folder in the web view of Gmail, just hover your mouse over the "Imap/Trash" Label and you should see a small downward pointing arrow one the label, click this and you should see the option to hide the problem label from both the "message list" and the "label list".